# Bifurcation diagram and classification

Tags: stability-theory, bifurcation, fixed-points

I am asked to sketch the bifurcation diagram for
$\dot{x}=x(\mu+x-2)(\mu+2x-x^2)$ and to state the type of bifurcation at each point.

I've set the RHS to $0$ to get the fixed points $x=0$, $x=2-\mu$, and $x=1\pm\sqrt{\mu+1}$. 
I am unsure how to find the bifurcation points and to classify the types of bifurcations.

Also, I would appreciate any articles or books explaining the basic things about bifurcations.